# When can the key in DatabaseReference be nil?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just updated the Firebase SDK from `5.0.2` to `5.0.3` and now I'm facing compilation errors.

One of them is due to the fact that property `key` used to be defined as `var key: String { get }` in the version `5.0.2` and is now defined as `var key: String? { get }` in `5.0.3`.

I couldn't find any explanation regarding the reason it became nilable and the documentation only states:

```
Gets the last token in a Firebase Database location (e.g. 'fred' in https&#58;//SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred)
@return The key of the location this reference points to.
```

Because it imply a lot of refactoring in my code I'd like to understand the reason of such a big change and when the `key` property become nil.

Comment: You've defined a variable called *key* e.g. *var key: String?* that is *optional*, which means it can be nil. What is the question?

Comment: @Jay sorry I meant Firebase SDK and not "my SDK"

Comment: The question is unclear, please clarify and we'll take a look!

Comment: @Jay I updated the question. Hope it's more clear cause if it's not, I don't see how I can do it. Thanks

Comment: Are say saying that by updating your Firebase SDK, it *changed the code in **your** project*? Where is *var key: String* defined? Can you include a code sample to clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay no the var `key` is a property the object `DatabaseReference` of the Firebase database SDK

Comment: It's unclear where you are seeing that. Also *String?... the key property become nil.* doesn't mean it became nil; it's an optional which could have a nil state. I looked at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(py)key) and don't see any mention of it being an optional. In the actual API, it's defined as *@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) NSString* key;*. It's a read-only property in my projects I don't need to unwrap it so it doesn't appear to be optional.

Comment: Oh - and if you try to force unwrap it like this *let x = some_firebase_ref.key!* the compiler complains with *Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'* which again, indicates it's not an optional of String?. Can you point us to where you are seeing this issue and supply some source code that duplicates the problem?

Comment: @Jay I've seen that in their SDK's header and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#key). I don't want to try to force unwrap it but it will change a lot of my code and some logic as well so that's why I'd like to understand the reason for such a change and when this happens.

Comment: I threw out some interesting info in an answer. Can you provide a use case (update your question) where you have to refactor your code to deal with this change? I have a number of projects that I have updated and am not having any issues with *var key:String? { get }* so maybe we can find an easy solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info from Firebase Support that may serve as an explanation and partial answer.

> If you have a DatabaseReference to the *root* of the database, the key
>   **will** be nil.

which means that a key will be nil in the case of a DatabaseReference to the root, or will have a value for other references, hence it would be defined as an optional. So this makes sense

```
var key:String? { get }
```

which then has a proof:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference() //points to the root ref
print(ref)
print(ref.key)
```

and the output

```
https://some_firebase.firebaseio.com
nil
```

If you think about it, given a conceptual Firebase reference like this

```
let usersRef = "https://some_firebase.firebaseio.com/users"
```

when you ask for key property, it's derived from the path

```
print(usersRef.key)  //prints Optional("users")

"https://some_firebase.firebaseio.com/users"
                                      ^^^^^ the key
```

and in the case of the root DatabaseReference there is no path to get the key from.

Comment: Where did you see "If you have a DatabaseReference to the root of the database, the key will be nil."? Was that a private support message or something public?

Comment: @JakeG It was a support response and the presented logic appears sound.

Comment: That part makes sense, I was just hoping to get a definitive answer if this is the only expected case of `key` being nil or if there were other possibilities.

Comment: @JakeG Other than this case, a Firebase Key will never be nil as Firebase doesn't have nil. Firebase has two states; a path either exists or or doesn't exist and there is no nil state. DataSnapshots have a .exists() function which can be used to test for existing data.

Comment: I understand that, but again, I am just curious about that being documented instead of assumed since there is a non-zero possibility that the SDK will return nil.

Comment: @JakeG Yeah - agreed. Do you perhaps have a use case, outside of the root reference, where having a nil key would be applicable? Maybe if it's posted as a clear question one of the Firebasers can address it.

Comment: Oh - and the quote in my answer was from @FrankvanPuffelen from Firebase.